# Did Goku actually die near end of Frieza saga? Plothole?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

So I am going through and rewatching Dragonball Z with my wife and noticed something.  When Goku is fighting Freiza as a SSJ, he gets sent into lava during the process of King Kai's wish for bringing back everyone that "Frieza and his henchmen killed".

**So my first question is:**

`Did Goku die in this moment?` Seems that the events went as follows:

1. King Kai starts wish
2. Goku goes into lava and dies.
3. Goku is brought back to life from King Kai's wish
4. Goku is much more powerful and full of energy (finally having the edge over Freiza vs before these events when it was a pretty much stalemate)

This makes me think that `yes Goku died` but then this reveals a plot hole as the wish was made with the earth dragonballs which were stated many times to not be able to revive someone already revived from them before. Well Goku was revived for the Vegeta / Nappa arc already. Plot hole?

**Second question:**

After Namek blows up it is said by King Kai if someone were to be wished back they would appear wherever they died and basically making it so Goku can't be wished back since Namek is gone but later Vegeta states they can wish someone back to the Earth's check-in station and then wished back to life.

So they do they following 3 wishes:

1. Ask for Krillin to be wished to the Earth's check-in station
2. Wish Krillin back to life. Seems to work based on rules.
3. Wish Yamcha back to life. He doesn't have to be wished to the check-in station as well?

Is this because Yamcha was in a "safe place"? `Why did't they need two wishes like they did with Krillin?`

FYI, even though I know many documented plot holes exist, and I could very well be wrong with my logic above, I enjoy learning things that I may have missed and having the discussion at least

Comment: This is 2 distinct questions

Comment: @SamIam Questions are in bold. How can I be more clear? On other SE sites, asking 2 questions are permitted. Is this not true here?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, *Goku never dies in the Frieza Saga*

This issue is  mainly because of a few changes in the anime from the original manga. In the manga basically, Freeza rushes Goku suddenly and knocks him into the ocean(there is no lava) and during the interval of all this happening, Shenron is called to grant the wishes and Goku meanwhile resurfaces and resumes fighting Frieza. In the anime, they did make a few changes and I believe it is only out of sheer coincidence Goku emerged out of the lava when the wish was made. Plus this is technically filler and Goku never dies in the Frieza Saga and even if he did, he cannot be revived as he was already revived when he was killed during his fight with Raditz at the start of the Saiyan saga.

With regard to your second question, Krillin died on Namek while Yamcha died on earth.

So these aren't necessarily plot holes.

Comment: So since Yamcha's place of death was Earth, upon resurrection he would appear where he died on earth (a tad off in location from his actual death spot but close enough) whereas Krillin needed to move first. Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @EricF Well someone isn't necessarily resurrected to the precise location they died(Meaning, not the precise latitude/longitude of a specific location). That is solely dependent on a bunch of factors of the shoe. But yes! A person seems to get resurrected on the planet he died on which is why, Vegeta comes back to life on Namek and since Krillin died on Namek and the planet exploded, they had to make the wish accordingly.